# Does the Event Listeners in javascript deal only with the user interaction or with scripts too?

Tags: javascript

I have three inputs namely, field1, field2, and resultField. I have attached event listeners to the first of two respectively and am getting their values and subtracting the first one from the second one. I am assigning their result to the result field which serves as an "input" for the result Field. I have then attached an event Listener to the result Field but the problem is the event listener won't fire as soon as it receives the evaluated input from field1 and field2. Please find my code below.

```js
let field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
let field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
let resultField = document.getElementById("fieldResult");
let value1 = field1.value;
let value2 = field2.value;

field1.addEventListener("input", result);
field2.addEventListener("input", result);
resultField.addEventListener("input", alertFunc);

function result() {
  value1 = field1.value;
  value2 = field2.value;
  let resultValue = value1 - value2;
  resultField.value = resultValue;
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("We have an input in result Field.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="field1">Filed 1</label>
  <input type "number" id="field1"></input>
  <label for="field2">Filed 2</label>
  <input type "number" id="field2"></input>
  <label for="fieldResult">Result Filed</label>
  <input type "number" id="fieldResult" readonly></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the alert as soon as the resultField gets the value? You shouldn't input in the resultField. Result Field must receive value from the result function.

Comment: You can call "alertFunc" inside result but need to check both input value

Comment: This is my question why isn't the eventFiring after the result field receives input? Is it not considered an input this way?

Comment: Please check input EventListener

Comment: I geht the alert, when I type something in the result field.

Comment: Don't type anything in the result field. Result field is getting input from the calculation of field1 and field 2.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you are talking about. You want to get an alert, if you change the value of th result field via JavaScript?

Comment: You have added event listener on Input and you are saying don't add anything to input. so how will that even listener listen ?

Comment: What you need is a debounce that will wait for few milliseconds for user to finish input in both fields and when both of them are finished it will fill the value in third field and show alert

Comment: @Apollo79 Yes. That is what I want. Does event Listener consider "manual" input an input or does it not consider input done via a script an input?

Comment: Yes, then you will need, as @prograk said, a setInterval function that checks the returl value field all 500 milliseconds or something like that and look for a change in this function

Comment: I think the OP's question is about does the `Event Listener` in JS only works with the user behavior? Correct me if I'm wrong. @AliMustafa

Comment: @You This is my question. I was unable to phrase it well.

Comment: @AliMustafa Good question btw. I suggest you update the post title & content to be more specific.

Comment: Setting an input's value programmatically will not trigger any events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event are not fired if you update an input value with js (you have to explicitly fired it)

Event are send by browser when there is browser action (load, online...) or user action (click, keyup...) but not when you do myfield.value=

you have to explicitly fire the event after you update the field value with

```
 resultField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```js
let field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
let field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
let resultField = document.getElementById("fieldResult");
let value1 = field1.value;
let value2 = field2.value;

field1.addEventListener("input", result);
field2.addEventListener("input", result);
resultField.addEventListener("input", alertFunc);

function result() {
  value1 = field1.value;
  value2 = field2.value;
  let resultValue = value1 - value2;
  resultField.value = resultValue;
  resultField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("We have an input in result Field.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="field1">Filed 1</label>
  <input type "number" id="field1"></input>
  <label for="field2">Filed 2</label>
  <input type "number" id="field2"></input>
  <label for="fieldResult">Result Filed</label>
  <input type "number" id="fieldResult" readonly></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not "unfortunately", we're lucky it doesn't trigger an `input` event.

Comment: @connexo Could you please explain why we are lucky if it doesn't trigger an event? This is a feature?

Comment: Because that would very easily create myriads of infinite loops.